# Monero GUI self-hosted node issue with Ledger - it keeps requesting password

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, ledger

I am running the most recent version of Monero GUI for Mac and Ledger firmware (I just updated the Ledger firmware and just downloaded and setup Monero GUI this weekend).

Everything went smoothly overall. Sent the private key from Ledger, setup the hardware wallet with the connected Monero GUI wallet, started to sync using the daemon and blocks started downloading. Then my issue started happening:

After some time of inactivity, I think about 20 mins to an hour, the Monero wallet decides to lock itself, the daemon stops syncing, and I have to go back to my computer and re-enter the Monero GUI password.

I already changed my Ledger options so that it doesn't auto-lock itself, as I assumed that was the issue. However, even without the Ledger self-locking, the Monero GUI keeps requesting a password and stopping the daemon. At this rate, it will take a very long time for my node to sync and for my wallet to be usable.

I searched extensively for this specific issue and seems like it's at least somewhat unique. I looked for options in the Monero GUI to not auto-lock after inactivity but couldn't find anything.

Hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [selsta](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/bmjmlz/monero_gui_wallet_constantly_logging_out_during/emx1mix?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x):

> You can disable this in Settings -> Layout -> Lock wallet on inactivity.